# Function with if-else doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript

I made a function which should disable a button if a variable isn't greater than or equal to another one. This function is run every second on a setInterval(), and the first variable to compare is also incremented by one on the setInterval(). But, the function (evitarNegs()),  isn't working properly, and the button is always disabled. Sorry that part of the code is in spanish.

**Javascript:**

```
var GmB = {cantidad: 0, perSec: 1};

function Upgrade (pb, ps) {
    this.precioBase = pb;
    this.perSec = ps;
    this.cantidad = 0;
    this.precio = pb;
}

Upgrade.prototype.comprar = function() {
    GmB.cantidad = GmB.cantidad - this.precio;
    GmB.perSec = GmB.perSec + this.perSec;
    this.cantidad++;
    document.getElementById("gmb").innerHTML = GmB.cantidad;
    this.precio = Math.ceil(this.precioBase*Math.pow(1.15, this.cantidad));
    evitarNegs();
};

function loop() {
    GmB.cantidad = GmB.cantidad + GmB.perSec;
    document.getElementById("gmb").innerHTML = GmB.cantidad;
    evitarNegs();
}

var upg = new Upgrade(10, 1);
var boton1 = document.getElementById("boton1");
boton1.disabled = true;
window.setInterval(loop, 1000);

//Problematic function
function evitarNegs() {
    if (!(GmB >= upg.precio)) {
        boton1.disabled = true;
    }else {
        boton1.disabled = false;
    }
}

boton1.onclick = function() {
    upg.comprar();
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gummy Bears</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="gmb">0</p>
        <button id="boton1" type="button">Upgrade 1</button>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing `GmB` to `upg.precio`, but `GmB` is an object. So you want

```
function evitarNegs() {
    if (!(GmB.cantidad >= upg.precio)) {
        boton1.disabled = true;
    } else {
        boton1.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

However, this can be written much easier as

```
function evitarNegs() {
    boton1.disabled = GmB.cantidad < upg.precio;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4rRmp/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are comparing an object to an integer in `GmB >= upg.precio`. You probably have to replace it by `GmB.cantidad >= upg.precio`.